# How to disable dock in some apps in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I've enabled the "Auto-hide the Dock" option in settings. So the dock pops out when I move the cursor down. But it is very useless in some applications.
How can I fully disable the dock in certain apps?

Comment: @user535733, sorry, i forgot that i am using 22.04 now. I just enabled "auto-hide the dock" option in settings/appearance and didn't "make" something.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the dock is not revealed by moving the cursor to the edge of the screen, turn "autohide" off:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide false
```

Reset to default with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide
```

As such, you can not have this change applied automatically when a specific application is in focus (unless you are rather advanced in scripting, perhaps). However, you can assign the commands to enable (replace `false` by `true`) or disable autohide to shortcut keys to be able to quickly change the setting.

You may also set up a single shortcut key that toggles the setting with a little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=$(gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide)
case $STATUS in
    true )
        gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide false
    ;;
    false )
        gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true
    ;;
esac
```

To create the script, 1) copy the code into a text file `~/.local/bin/autohide_dock`. 2) Make that file executable (right-click, "Properties", "Permissions" tab. 3) Create a shortcut key and provide the file path of the executable script as the command: `/home/<yourlogin>/.local/bin/autohide_dock`